# rewrite url must contain slash at the end of the url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I use url-rewrite to easy the process of finding a folder, but when someone enters something like this:

```
http ://domain.com/folder1/folder2
```

it returns a lot of errors.

Is there a chance of telling rewrite engine to automatically add slash at the end?
That meaning to change:

```
http ://domain.com/folder1/folder2
```

to:

```
http ://domain.com/folder1/folder2/
```

The file does not actually exist. I use ajax and History.pushState to change the url while ajax reads the folder.

And is there any GOOD online tutorial about rewriteEngine (not youtube)?

Comment: Which server are you using? Apache, nginx,iis, tomcat or something else?

Comment: I'm using Apache ---> .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

If  `/folder2`  exists as directory in your filesystem ,then the following rule should add a traling slash to the uri :

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule !/$ /$0/ [L,R]
```

Comment: Ouu yes I forgot. folder2 does not exist the url is added up by History.pushState. That means that there can be a lot more than one folder. Ex. http ://domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4...